# How do I create a KineticJS stage based on size acquired using JQuery so it resizes with a div that has a Bootstrap img-responsive class?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, kineticjs

I'm applying `img-thumbnail img-responsive` classes to a div that I use as the KineticJS stage.

I want the stage to fill the div and resize with it. I thought this might work but it doesn't:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'map',
    width: $("#map").width(),
    height: $("#map").height()
  });
});
```

Are there other ways of doing this or a way to make this work?

Comment: When the browser resizes, use stage.setScale to resize all the Kinetic stuff.

Comment: I ended up trying something similar to that. Thank you but this turned out to not be as smooth as using straight-up HTML5 canvas. I think I'm just gonna find another way of implementing what I want.